# Is my proof rigorous? (Archimedes area of parabola)

Tags: calculus, inequality, proof-verification, area

I am currently reading Apostol's Calculus volume 1 and was revising the part where the area of a parabolic segment is found. I decided to write my own proof similar to the one in the book, which I found too complicated to really understand (not logically, but just motivation wise because he doesn't explain things like how you can think of $1^2+2^2+\cdots+(n-1)^2 < n^3/3 < 1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2$ and it just seems like he pulled a rabbit out of the hat when he states this inequality).

My main question is whether my proof is rigorous. Here goes:

We want to find the area of the parabola that has an ordinate $ax^2+c$ at $x$. We want to find this area from $x=0$ to $x=b$. So first we find upper and lower bounds, $\frac{ab^3}{n^3}f(n-1)+\frac{(n-1)bc}{n}<A<\frac{ab^3}{n^3}f(n)+bc$ where $A$ is the area. This must be true for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Our plan is simple: We try to "build" this inequality from a "primitive" inequality for which we know the middle term. In this way, if we can make the middle term constant at some step in the manipulation, and keep it constant, then by comparison we will know $A$. This is because, we will have an inequality of the form $\frac{ab^3}{n^3}f(n-1)+\frac{(n-1)bc}{n}<C<\frac{ab^3}{n^3}f(n)+bc$ for some constant $C$, and this will be true for all $n$. Therefore, since the area of a parabolic segment cannot have two values from $x=0$ to $x=b$, it must be that $A=C$, and we will know $A$ since we know $C$.

Now, what can this "primitive inequality" that we talked about look like. Well, it must be true for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, so that when we manipulate it into the desired form we end up with the "$C$" inequality being true for all $n$. Therefore it must be an inequality in $n$.

Also we see $f(n-1)$ and $f(n)$. Eventually therefore we might be led to consider the primitive inequality $f(n-1)<g(n)<f(n)$ for some function $g(n)$. We know that we must multiply this through by $\frac{ab^3}{n^3}$. We also know that we want $g(n)$ to be constant after this multiplication. Thus we consider $g(n)=kn^3$ for some constant $k$. It is easy to find therefore that $k=1/3$; indeed $f(n-1)<n^3/3<f(n)$ is true for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Now we start:

Multplying through by $\frac{ab^3}{n^3}$ gives $\frac{ab^3}{n^3}f(n-1)<\frac{ab^3}{3}<\frac{ab^3}{n^3}f(n)$ (the middle term constant like we wanted), then we add $bc$ to both sides rather than $\frac{(n-1)bc}{n}$ (to keep the middle term constant) to get $\frac{ab^3}{n^3}f(n-1)+bc<\frac{ab^3}{3}+bc<\frac{ab^3}{n^3}f(n)+bc$. Finally we see that $\frac{ab^3}{n^3}f(n-1)+\frac{(n-1)bc}{n}<\frac{ab^3}{n^3}f(n-1)+bc$ so that the last inequality becomes $\frac{ab^3}{n^3}f(n-1)+\frac{(n-1)bc}{n}<\frac{ab^3}{3}+bc<\frac{ab^3}{n^3}f(n)+bc$. So by comparison with the original inequality, we see that $A=\frac{ab^3}{3}+bc$ and we are done.

Comment: It would be a mistake to think that Archimedes did it by any method involving sums of squares of members of an arithmetic progression.  He used at least two different methods. One went like this: Draw a secant line $AB$ (do NOT assume $AB$ is orthogonal to the axis). It has a midpoint $C$. The line parallel to the axis through $C$ intersects the curve at $D$. We have a triangle $ABD$. Now construct triangles on the two secant lines $AD$ and $DB$ in the same way. Archimedes showed the sum of the areas of these two new triangles is $1/4$ the area of the big triangle $ABD$. Then${}\,\ldots\ \ {}$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$then construct four more still smaller triangles on the four so-far drawn secant lines closest to the curve.  The same argument shows that their total area is $1/4$ of the area of those two triangles constucted.  And so on.  You have an infinite series $1+\frac14 + \frac1{16} + \frac1{64}+\cdots = \frac 4 3$.  The area bounded by the curve and the secant line $AB$ has $4/3$ the area of the triangle $ABD$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Archimedes' way of summing the series used the following proposition (which I write in modern notation): The value of $1 + \frac14 + \frac1{4^2} + \frac1{4^3} + \cdots + \frac1{4^n} + \left(\frac1{4^n}\cdot\frac13\right)$ does not depend on $n$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Your proof does make any sense.  What are f(n) and f(n+1).  Also, how do you get the first inequality.  I get that your are trying to approximate the area by some kind of sequence, but its not clear.

Comment: Archimedes had another method using the concept of center of gravity. I think he may have been the first ever to write about centers of gravity. He said the center of gravity of the region bounded by a triangle is on the line from any one vertex to the midpoint of the opposite side, two-thirds of the way along. Then he considered a secant line $AB$ of a parabola (again, NOT necessarily orthogonal to the axis) and he drew (1) a TANGENT LINE at $B$ and (2) a line PARALLEL TO THE AXIS at $A$. These meet at $C$. Archimideds said the area bounded by the secant line $AB$ and the curve is${}\,\ldots$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}1/3$ the area of that triangle.  To prove this, he drew the line passing through $B$ and the midpoint $D$ of $AC$, and considered it a lever whose fulcrum is at $D$. If the whole weight of the region bounded by $\triangle ABC$ rests at the center of gravity, which is a certain point on the lever, it exerts a certain torque. It is enough to show that if the weight of the region bounded by the parabola and the secant $AB$ rests at $B$, it exerts that SAME torque. So draw cross-section $EF$ of $\triangle ABC$ parallel to the axis, crossing the curve at $G$. Then${}\,\ldots\qquad{}$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$ let the infinitesimal weight of the cross-section $EF$ rest at the point where it crosses the lever. These infinitely many infinitely small weights exert the same torque as the whole weight of the triangle at the center of gravity. So the question is: if the weight of $EF$ rests where it crosses the lever, and the weight of $GF$ (where $F$ is on the secant $AB$) rests at $B$, do they both exert the SAME torque? However, _that_ is merely the equation of the parabola.  Q.E.D. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Note that his second proof seems to work only if we can speak of infinitesimals, but his first proof works only if there are no nonzero infinitesimals.  The latter is because the area of the parabola is shown to differ from $1 + \frac14 + \frac1{4^2} + \frac1{4^3} + \cdots$ by an infinitesimal.  So if $0$ is the only infinitesimal, the proof works. ${}\qquad{}$